# Extended regular expressions - Think I might be too restrictive in my search but not sure

Tags: regex, linux, expression

I'm trying to figure out this extended expression to search a txt file for specific lines using the following parameters:

- lines that contain a seven-digit number,
- surrounded before and after with non-digit characters,
- with one or more dashes or underscores between the third and fourth digits.

These should match:

```
x555-1212x
x555__1212x
x555-_-1212x
```

but these would not match:

```
x999555-1212x
x555-1212999x x999555-1212999x
555-121x
x55-1212
5551212
```

Here's what I've tried and it's giving me 5 out of the 7 required lines according to a checking script

```
egrep '[^0-9]+[[:digit:]]{3}[-_]+[[:digit:]]{4}[^0-9]+' foo.txt
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this...whether I'm being too restrictive and eliminating certain white space characters like Tab or something else.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The regex and the sample data do exactly what your English language description of the match is suggesting?

Comment: Can you give an example line for what should have been matched that hasn't?

Comment: The non-matches in the edited post are still perfectly in line with the English description of your expectation.  Why would you expect them to match?

Comment: those matches and non-matches are examples from the question of what you should be looking for or not looking for, not actually in the text...the actual text is 15000 lines long.

Comment: But the ones that _wouldn't_ match **shouldn't** match given your description.  Where do you see the problem?

Comment: I'm thinking the regex is too restrictive because it only gives 5...should be 7.  Does anyone know if [^0-9] filters out tab character or other white space characters that are not a space?

Comment: To quote @inhan:  can you give an example line that should have been matched that hasn't been?  I still don't see what makes you unhappy.

Comment: One thing stands out to me - the `[^0-9]+` at the beginning *must* match at least one character - so acceptable patterns that start at the beginning of the line will not match. Same story with the one at the end... You may want to make those read `[^0-9]*` instead to match zero or more...

Comment: @twalberg:  The OP still hasn't explained what his own regex is doing wrong, but changing the `[^0-9]+` to `[^0-9]*` can't possibly help.  It allows matches like `999555-1212` and `555_1212999`, which are definitely on the don't-match list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in **lines** that have your pattern you could use start `^` and end `$` RegEx operators in your matching pattern.

RegEx: `^.*?(\D|^)(\d{3}[-_]+\d{4})(\D|$).*?$`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/gQ0cE2